# Ignore files for the npm build

Tags: reactjs, file, npm, build

When I build my React app using  `npm run-script build` there are a folder and a file that I don't want to be there.
Is there a way to ignore the file and the folder during the npm run-script build?
I know there are the .gitignore and the .npmignore but there are used to ignore the files only for the publication (not the build).

Thank you.

Comment: What folder and file is it you don't want in there? Are they in your `public` folder? If you can't remove them from the `src`, you could do `npm run build && rm -rf ./build/myfolder ./build/myfile`

Comment: No they are a folder containing pictures (Yes I know I shouldn't have done that) and a json file with some data. I tried your command and `npm run-script build && rm -rf ./src/myfolder ./src/myfile` and I still had the files built in the build directory.

Comment: You should remove the folder and json file from the *build* folder, not `src` folder.

Comment: The build command creates a `build` folder with all assets in it. You then remove the files you don't want from that. Are you saying you want to remove e.g. `import json from './myjson.json'`? Why do you even import it at all then?

Comment: The build generates a single file called main.aed18c57.js with all my code(javascript/json) so unless I remove them manually line by line... The app uses a sort of database which is stored in the src folder. But when I build the app, it generates a static file and the "database" cannot be modified. Maybe if the database isn't built, the built app will use the database stored in src folder instead of the "static database" of the build directory.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a pretty old thread, but like I faced recently this problem, so I think this might help others.

Like Thottle mentioned in a comment, using `rm -rf ./filePathToExclude` pattern in build scripts can help. The only change that worked for me was to put `rm -rf /.filePathToExclude` before `react-scripts build`.

The final build script that worked for me (for excluding .env file, that is in the same directory as package.json) was `rm -rf ./.env && react-scripts build`.

Comment: Or u can exclude the folder from `tsconfig.json` if u're using TypeScript